# Inserting data into database using html forms

Tags: php, html, database

Okay, guys. I am new at php and other server side codes.

I am able to connect successfully to my server and database. I am able to use the Insert data code to insert data with values. However, when I enter the values into the code, those are the values that get sent to the table. How do I use HTML forms to use custom data entered into text areas to show up in my database table?

**For example,**

when I use VALUE ('jon', 'doe') it sends those values into the database instead of the text I enter into the text areas. How do I fix this to say, enter my actual name when I fill out a web form?

Basically, I am asking how I would use web forms to manipulate data into the database. I'm so confused

Comment: Please, show what have you tried and what errors you get.

Comment: You could start hear http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php and then for database https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow (SO)! FYI: SO is not the place to ask general questions, that require long answers or need a discussion. You should read the manuals from the developer sites, make your experience and ask your concrete questions at a point, where you can not find a special solution or have a bug. You should provide your code so far and explain, what it is intended to do, what actually is happening and what you have tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are encouraged to use **PDO** (or at least mysqli) **prepared** statements from the first day. This way you can relatively safely insert data into your SQL statements. Please read the [official manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Be aware that PDO will *emulate* prepared statements by default. That can result in a security hole. Therefore you should request to switch of emulated prepared statements.

```
$options       = [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false];
$pdoConnection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
```

You can then create prepared SQL statements like:

```
SELECT `id`, `value` FROM `myTable` WHERE `value` = ?;
```

As long as the driver supports real prepared statements, the "?" will not be substituted directly, data will be separately sent after the statement. This avoids SQL injection via encoding attacks.

Please read documentation, try things out and come back if you have concrete questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a form on one page that sends input to another page. For example:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="action.php">
      <input type="text" name="message">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your php/MySQL code would then exist in a page called action.php which would be located in the same directory as index.php.

action.php:

```
<?php
$message = $_POST['message'];
/*now you can use the $message variable in your MySQL code to insert
it into the database*/
?>
```

Please remember to used prepared statements and to bind your parameters in your MySQL code to prevent hacker attacks (like sql injection).

Let me know if that worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

When creating a form in html you may define the following input:

```
<input type="text" name="my_input">
```

To access the content of this particular input, after submission of the form. Use depending on what method your form is using `$_GET['my_input']` or `$_POST['my_input']` to retrieve the value entered in the form input.

Try to play arround with this example:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="field" value="<?php print $_GET['field']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="s" value="Go!">
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
    print "value of the text field: ".$_GET['field'];
}
```